# Joomla blog load in article, is it possible

Tags: joomla, blogs

I am using joomla and have created a blog in my main menu using "CATEGORY BLOG" .
I would like to post part of that on my frontpage, is that possible.

For example can i have "Category blog" as part of an article ???
That would be quite helpfull

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are a lot free extensions that do this easily. I suggest you to try [RokSprocket](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/roksprocket/) Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Category blog is more or less the equivalent of the "Articles Category" module. Just create an "Articles Category" module, link it to the same category (and order it the same way), and then load it in the article using {loadposition }. You may need to override the layout of the "Articles Category" module in your template to ensure a consistent look.